# Rails 4+: do not retrieve sensitive attributes from DB by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, select, activerecord

This a contrived example but I hope it demonstrates my question.  No, I'm not storing passwords in plaintext, etc; this is just an example.

```
User.create(name: "John", password: "sensitive")
User.all => [{User: name: "John", password: "sensitive"}]
```

When I retrieve data from the DB, I do not want the `password` attribute returned by default, such that:

```
User.all => [{User: name: "John"}]
```

I assumed ActiveRecord would have a method in the model I could override to establish the default attributes to select, but I can't find such a method.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Active Record loads all the attributes. There is no concept of "sensitive" attribute. In fact, as long as you don't dump the instance anywhere (e.g. using inspect), or you don't print out the attribute, there is really not a lot security issues associated with fetching that data (of course, assuming you have a secure connection).

Perhaps you should explain what is the issue that is bringing you to believe that not loading that attribute would be the best solution to the problem.

It's also important to remember that several Rails defaults will loop over all attributes, whenever you try to use features such as `to_json`. My suggestion is to avoid relying on those features, but always explicitly whitelist the attributes you want to use or export. That would prevent leakage of sensible details.

Last but not least, you can try to workaround the Rails defaults by using a method that enumerates all the attributes, without the ones you consider "sensible"

```
Model.select(Model.column_names - %w( password other )).all
```

`select` applies to any query method:

```
Model.select(Model.column_names - %w( password other )).find(54)
Model.select(Model.column_names - %w( password other )).first
```

Comment: If you _really_ wanted to, you could implement Simone's solution with default_scope. But be aware that [default_scope is evil](http://www.ombulabs.com/blog/ruby/rails/best-practices/why-using-default-scope-is-a-bad-idea.html).